# how to get all links from website quickly

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am developing a application. In this application, I need to scrape all links from 2000+ websites. Before I used urlopen to scrape all the links from these websites. Then I found some pages returned "javascript is disabled...". Hence I have to switch to Selenium to scrape these links. I have to create driver and close it for more than thousand times. Is there anyway to do it faster? Sometimes opening up driver and closing took very long time.

old code:

```
            req = urllib.request.Request(url=url,headers=hdr)
            resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req,timeout=10)
            html = resp.read().decode()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
```

new code:

```
chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory" : download_dir}) 
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222') # http://localhost:9222/
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)
    
driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)

# get url specified by user
driver.get(url)
html_str = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str, "html.parser")
driver.close()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with selenium but can't you create the driver once and then call `driver.get(url)` (and the following lines except the `close`) in a loop? If not, using threads might be an option.

Comment: Using `driver.get(url)` in a loop without closing driver is an option. If you need to check each URL with clean Session you can drop Cookies in the end of each iteration

Comment: what if some urls return errors when calling driver.get(url)